# Singular constraint in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

How am I going to go about solving this with only a singular constraint and an unknown?

Refer to the following LP Formulation with unknown number S:

Max x1+x2

s.t

Sx1+x2 <= 1
x1,x2 => 0

How do I identify the unknown S to

(a) Having an optimal solution
(b) Being infeasible
(c) Being Unbound

Comment: Not about programming. Looks like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the homework due date has probably passed, I thought I'd answer this because it is a little tricky.  (b) almost got me..

(a) S>=0

(b) feasible for all S

(c) S<0